# How to add icons to post listing (edit.php) in admin

Tags: filters, admin

Is there a filter or something to add these kind of icons based categories and what not to all posts?

[image]

I can't seem to find one. I tried the_title but ofc that gets sanitized and just displays the html..
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can style the table with CSS and *dashicons*.

### Example:

For our `video` category, we can use for example:

```
.edit-php .wp-list-table tr.category-video td.post-title strong:before {
    content: "\f126";
    color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-family: "dashicons";
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

where we target the `tr.category-video` class.

Just check out how it's used in the backend, to get an idea of the CSS attributes.

We can get the list of dashicons [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/).

### Update:

[Here's](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1f75220e9a24482ea1f95920d390c5083542161d/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L730-734) it the part of the `WP_Posts_List_Table`  class that displays the post format icon:

```
$pad = str_repeat( '&#8212; ', $level );
echo "<td $attributes><strong>";    
if ( $format = get_post_format( $post->ID ) ) {
    $label = get_post_format_string( $format );

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_format' =>  
             $format, 'post_type' => $post->post_type ), 'edit.php' ) ) . '" 
             class="post-state-format post-format-icon post-format-' . $format 
             . '" title="' . $label . '">' . $label . ":</a> ";
}
```

Comment: Oh my now I feel stupid. I DID check the source multiple times but I totally missed the `<tr>` classes somehow. Thanks mate.

Comment: don't worry, this also happens to me all the time ;-) Sometimes we just need to borrow another pair of eyes for a minute. I would consult the admin style in the core regarding the dashicon CSS commands. @jimihenrik

Comment: Yeah true, but I'm still intrigued. The native formats (video/gallery) etc have and extra HTML element there anyway, not just classes, so wondering if one could be added via a filter.

Comment: You mean the post format icon? There doesn't seem to be any  explicit filter to modify this output. I updated the answer with the corresponding code in the core. You might try CSS or Javascript to modify it to your needs.  @jimihenrik

Comment: Damn. And there's no `set_post_format` either. So I'm fresh outta luck with that one then. But well, the _hack_ you provided is more than enough for now anyway. I tried to look at the source too but I was lazy, even though I realized it was the posts_list_table that did the work I didn't have the work ethic to dig that far. Well, was lazy < got answers so...

Comment: Well there exists [`set_post_format`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_format), but I'm not sure how flexible this is regarding other formats than the default ones. It looks like we are stuck with the default formats defined in `get_post_format_strings()`. @jimihenrik

Answer (score 0):

```
tr.type-post td.column-title strong:before {
color: #ccc;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 4px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "dashicons";
font-weight: normal;
vertical-align: top;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}
tr.post_format-post-format-link td.column-title strong:before {
content: "\f103";}
tr.post_format-post-format-video td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f126";}
tr.post_format-post-format-audio td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f127";}tr.post_format-post-format-image td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f128";}tr.post_format-post-format-gallery td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f161";}tr.post_format-post-format-chat td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f125";}tr.post_format-post-format-quote td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f122";}tr.post_format-post-format-aside td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f123";}
tr.post_format-post-format-status td.column-title strong:before {
content:"\f130";}
```

Comment: 9 years later  But thanks  Pure css won't help you getting them per category or any custom variable though 